# Ubuntu 16.04.3 sees unallocated space as a NTFS partition

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning

When installing Ubuntu 16.04.3 from a USB flash drive, i encountered a problem, when trying to specify where to install Ubuntu. I have Windows 7 and Zorin OS installed on one of my drives, everything works perfectly, grub detects Windows and Zorin, I can use both of them.

But when I formatted one of my additional HDDs, and was hoping to install Ubuntu on it, by creating additional partitions for swap and Ubuntu itself, Ubuntu failed to recognize the unallocated space, that was created after formatting. Instead, it still thinks that that unallocated space is a NTFS partition.

My disk with unallocated space is an MBR disk.

Has somebody encountered this before? Is there a way to solve this problem?

[Here's a screenshot of my Disk Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuePs.png)

Comment: You must be selecting the wrong disk then. You have one disk with a single NTFS partition, by the way, and that is probably the one you're looking at.

Comment: When this happens reboot to reload the partition table

Comment: @Panther, yes, rebooting helped. Now everything is back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

After making partitions you often need to reboot to reload the partition table. From the comments, rebooting solved the problem.